# How do I assign the output of jq to variables?

Tags: json, bash, variables, jq

I am attempting to parse NOAA NWS json data with jq.  My last computer class was as a senior in high school, '67-68 semester.  Be gentle.

I have figured out how to filter the data I want, but I'd like it assigned to variables so I can use it farther down the road.  Using the original json name and index number as the variable's name is where I'm aimed.  I can't find any documentation that even gives me a clue, but I'm guessing this is something jq is used for all-the-time.

Here are my data and filters:  https://jqplay.org/s/uRhNX-UglJ?fbclid=IwAR3lPxOj1fQcyzEOSrvf5x3WBQWXd0N1kwTc62Agmg1KANwkKL6hI-0vJOE

Answer (score 0):

So not sure if this will help, but I use a JSON prettifier tool to get the arrays & indices info that I need
(the first one is a little more helpful to me)

- https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer
- http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

and from there I wrote a bash script that takes in whatever I'm getting data about as a variable, query it, and then use jq and awk to print whatever I'm after

Here's a line from the script showing the data I'm looking for:

```
res=$(curl --silent "https://api.oraclize.it/v1/query/eth_mainnet_${rec}/status" | jq -r ".result.checks[0].results")
        echo "$res"|awk '{print $2}'
```

If I can provide anything further please feel free to reach out but maybe this will get you pointed in the right direction